# SQL Error in Google Big Query with UNION ALL on tables with same schema EDIT:

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM CaseStudy.Apr22 A
UNION All
SELECT * FROM CaseStudy.Aug22 B
```

I get the following error on the second SELECT call

> Column 14 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME,

The column name is ride_lenth .

I am trying to make one large table from several smaller ones - monthly tables of the same data.

I've tried to change to(below) but then my column disappears

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(ride_length), SAFE_CAST(ride_length AS STRING) AS ride_length
FROM CaseStudy.Apr22 A
UNION All
SELECT * EXCEPT(ride_length), SAFE_CAST(ride_length AS STRING) AS ride_length
FROM CaseStudy.Aug22 B
```

Comment: what do you mean *my column disappears* ? `ride_length`  will be shown in last in your table, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shared is appears to be correct so the challenge is with the data tables.

I have a couple of simple debugging tips that you have probably already tried, but might help point you in the right direction.

1. Check that the `ride_length` is not an ARRAY because that cannot be cast as a string and would explain safe case removing the column.
2. The `UNION` maybe failing because at least 1 record in `ride_length` is different to the others. When uploading some file type, BigQuery does not always check the formatting of the data and assumes it is the same as the previous file and problems only appear when you try to use them.

   > ```
   >         SELECT DISTINCT ride_length FROM CaseStudy.Apr22 A
   >         limit =10
   > ```

   > ```
   >         SELECT DISTINCT ride_length FROM CaseStudy.Aug22 B
   >         limit =10
   > ```

   should allow you to see the format of both tables are the same order by `DESC` and `ASC` to check top and bottom, where fields with different types and formats normally end up.
3. Check if there is something in the field that should not be there assuming `ride_length` is time, float64 or INT sum both of tables if one of the fields holds something that is not possible to sum `select sum(ride_length) FROM CaseStudy.Aug22 B` if it does not sum you have found where the problem is.